# Price of virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-cost-calculation

I have a $100 student subscription where I created VM inside a virtual network. I noticed I am being charged approximately $3.48 monthly for a virtual network. I am charged without using the disabled VM inside. Any idea of what is causing this?

The virtual network map displays the following: network interface, network security group, IP configuration, public IP addresses and the (disabled) VM.
[image]

(I am not able to use [Cost Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cost-management-billing/understand/analyze-unexpected-charges), since that is not available for student subscriptions.)

Comment: If you’ll look closely at what you’ve highlighted using a red box, you’re not being charged for the VNet itself but rather the public IP address associated with your VM. The costs of this are [well documented](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/), including the fact that you’re charged for the reservation of said address regardless of your VM’s state.